# How make bootstrap class="form-inline" work on resolutions < 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We are making a Google sites where we will put a form made on Bootstrap.

The width that we have to put the form is 500px;

The code its alright but the `<div class="form-inline">` just work on a specific size of screen, and we need to specify that size, where should we change that?

Thank you.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="Inputtel">Telefone</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Inputtel" placeholder="Telefone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="InputCPFCNPJ">CPF ou CNPJ</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="InputCPFCNPJ" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in bootstrap 3 you can use the grid options to do that.
It is right that you want the inputs in one line?
So you can solve your problem with col-xs-6. or you can use smaller input with col-xs-4.
test it ;)

```
<div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="Inputtel">Telefone</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Inputtel" placeholder="Telefone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="InputCPFCNPJ">CPF ou CNPJ</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="InputCPFCNPJ" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you chuebert thats works, but i have a button on the end of the form and the button stay with margin-left:0 and when i used col-xs-6 the elements have some margin, how can a manage that?

Comment: would you like the inputs and the button in one row? You can give the inputs col-xs-5 and button col-xs-2, the sum must be 12.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to achieve the result is to force che class "form-inline" works also with the resolution < 768px adding a simple css in your project:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

By the way, with small width windows can occur the possibility that not all your inline components can be rendered in the same row and some last components will go on the second row (if there aren't enough space).

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the max-width value, you should use the Bootstrap media query **@screen-xs-max** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries
For example:
***@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { }***

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was @Rancid solution but replaced

```
display: inline-block
```

by

```
display: inline-table
```

And it worked just fine, all elements in a single line.