# bootstrap Button alignment in form-inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

The button alignment inside the form-inline div goes off when the screen is reduced to small size. I have created below fiddle

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/koolhuman/a4zdoodu/2/

```
//section 1
<div class="form-inline">
                    <label>Enter Zip/Postal Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="localMarketPostalCode" name="localMarketPostalCode" size="5">
                    <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search" class="btn btn-success">
</div>

<br/>

//section2      
<div class="form-inline">
               <label>Search</label>
               <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
                <select id="searchon" name="searchon"> 
                    <option value="0">First Name</option>
                    <option value="1">Last Name</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
</div>
```

1) The first section is where the problem lies and has form-control class applied to the text box

2) In the second section the alignment is correct and form-control class is not applied to the text box

**Possible Cause**: I figured out the issue is with the form-control class which i have applied to the textbox in combination with the font-size. When i remove the font-size = 14px for the .form-control class the alignment of the button seems correct.

I was looking for a better way where i can overcome this alignment issue as well as can apply the form-control class to the textbox so all the bootstrap styling's are maintained.

[image]

Comment: you can try the flexbox

Comment: I think you will have to use a work-around. Directly from Bootstrap's website - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline - `Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a <form>) for left-aligned and inline-block controls. This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.`.

Comment: There is also a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651215/how-make-bootstrap-class-form-inline-work-on-resolutions-768px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just overwrite or change the button style property vertical-align in your own CSS. Change it from vertical-align: middle to "vertical-align: top" ... that should fix it.

```
.btn { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: yes i can certainly do it, but why does the vertical-align: middle not working on the smaller screen ? Cant we do it without overriding any default bootstrap classes ?

Comment: For now i will accept this answer unless we find a better way to do it. Thanks !!

Comment: Honestly, Bootstrap is not without its flaws. I agree there "should" be a better solution. Hopefully somebody comes along who can shine some more light on the issue.