# Bootstrap form-inline for viewports that are less than 768px wide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I achieve that all the form elements are in one line in the example below? The bootstrap class `form-inline` is not working on small viewports. From official bootstrap [site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms):

> This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px
>   wide.

```css
#containerGraph {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
}
/*  set the position attribute for all div elements inside the mainContainer*/

#containerGraph > div {
  position: absolute;
}
.paramElement {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: small;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.paramElementHeading {
  font-size: larger;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.paramElementForm {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.paramElementForm > input {
  width: 80px;
}
.column1 {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.column2 {
  margin-left: 163px;
}
.column3 {
  margin-left: 323px;
}
.column4 {
  margin-left: 483px;
}
.column5 {
  margin-left: 643px;
}
.column6 {
  margin-left: 803px;
}
.column7 {
  margin-left: 963px;
}
.column8 {
  margin-left: 1123px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerGraph">


  <div class="column1 paramElement" id="param1">
    <div class="paramElementHeading">
      Title Title Title Title
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline" style="width:30px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="focusedInput">Focused</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" style="width:auto;" id="sel1">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651215/how-make-bootstrap-class-form-inline-work-on-resolutions-768px?rq=1) similar question isn't working in my case. And I don't want to use the grid systems as mentioned in the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Check demo **[here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/mAzLyq?editors=1100)**

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-inline > .checkbox {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .form-inline .form-control {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .form-inline label {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

Comment: @d4rty I modified your code check the updated link [here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/GjLqoX?editors=1100)