# How to display two elements side by side in iPhone6?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a small Bootstrap 4 form with a row containing dropdown, search box and two buttons. When I view the page in iPhone 6, I see that the GO button goes below the search box. How can I have both search and GO button on the same line?

The Plnkr link is https://plnkr.co/edit/uJk6iE6NjBEXGcM2vhqT?p=preview

```
<div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 hidden-md-down">
                    <select class="custom-select">
                        <option selected>Sort by</option>
                        <option value="1">First Name</option>
                        <option value="2">Last Name</option>
                        <option value="3">Salary</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-action="grow" placeholder="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        <span class="icon icon-magnifying-glass">GO</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 hidden-md-down float-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-pill btn-success">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651215/how-make-bootstrap-class-form-inline-work-on-resolutions-768px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More about `input group` you can read documentation [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/)

Try this

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" data-action="grow" placeholder="Search">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
           <span class="icon icon-magnifying-glass">GO</span>
      </button>
  </span>
</div>
```